# I want to delete my React Native app I made using expo, but its telling me the folder is being used in another program

Tags: windows, files-folders

I made an test app using React Native, but now I want to delete it and start from scratch. I click on the file to delete it, but as it's going Windows gives me an error:
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuCiP.png)

I tried restarting my computer and trying it, using the command prompt, and checking to see if there's anything running in the task manger. Nothing

One way that does work, however, is booting windows into safe mode and then deleting the folder that way. But I don't want to have to do that every time I want to delete a folder from React Native.

Another strange thing is that I can delete everything in the folder(ex. config files, js files, etc, just not the folder itself.

Comment: It may be a bad locking handle.  Try Unlocker 1.9.2 . Try using Majogeeks as a decent site to find it. I use Unlocker on files that cannot be deleted, and then delete the empty folder.  Numerous Windows apps leave files behind with bad/no locking handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is a program called Eraser,

If you want to diagnose the issue, I'd start by removing programs running in the task manager. Some examples may be gDrive, or an antivirus... in msconfig you may be able to disable other programs (basically replicating safemode) you can also hold ctr shift while booting windows to skip the shortcuts in the startup folder(s).